# regex string @[name of some thing](stringId)

Tags: javascript, regex, split

I have a text with string content and a tag. I want to split the text into an array. I tried many ways but got some bugs @@

Input:

```
"This is a text with a @[name of tag](tagId). This is another @[name of another tag](tagId)"
```

Output:

```
array = ["This is a text with a ", "@[name of tag](tagId)", ". This is another " , "@[name of another tag](tagId)"]
```

The tag always has **@[** at begin, **)** at the end and **](** at between,

I tried

```js
const str = "This is a text with a @[name of tag](tagId). This is another @[name of another tag](tagId)"
const result = str.split(/[@[)]/);
console.log(result);
```

But that has many issues like "", " " or missing @[ in result

Thanks for all help

Comment: Please show us what you've tried (at least last version). On Stackoverflow you're supposed to do that so that people can help you understand the problem with your attempt.

Comment: @Jay I updated the last result I tried. I think my regex missing some condition in that. Thank you

Comment: @DangHoangVu: Does the name tag includes characters, spaces, digits etc.?
Does tagId includes digits, characters, spaces etc.
Can you provide the real example of whole input?